# Why am I getting a low L/D of 4.3 for this supercritical airfoil in Autodesk CFD?

Tags: aerodynamics, airfoil, cfd

I am a high school student learning to analyze aircraft models in Autodesk CFD for the first time. My current project is analyzing a supercritical airfoil on Autodesk CFD (that was designed in Autodesk Fusion360).

Can I get help with the following : I researched [several turbulence models in Autodesk](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/cfd/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/SimCFD-UsersGuide/files/GUID-E9E8ACA1-8D49-4A49-8A35-52DB1A2C3E5F-htm.html#:%7E:text=Turb.%20model%20%20%20Turbulence%20Model%20%20,model%20wi%20...%20%206%20more%20rows) and I chose the SST k omega turbulence model, with a 250 m/s inlet velocity, 0 gauge pressure , unknown outlet and a compressible flow.

I am getting a lift to drag ratio of approximately 4.3. I think the lift to drag ratio is too low. I am suspecting the analysis conditions are to blame. Are these the correct input parameters? Am I missing anything else?

Here is a screenshot of the analysis: I ran the airfoil analysis at angle of attack of 5°.

[image: 250m/s transonic analysis]